# How to put multiple value with comma in IN() Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am sending "4,5" getting it form option `<option value="4,5">` or `<option value="45">`(may be)

I have an sql query where i have to use this in IN () like `IN(4,5)` how can I format that and use in IN()

When i used this it says `invalid input syntax for integer: &quot;4,5&quot;`

can anyone suggest me something

```
It looks like that SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN (4,5)
```

Comment: You would need to show us your actual code.

Comment: Updated, please check @GMB

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with your driver or connection library, but you haven't told us what that is, or shown us any code.  The SQL you have shown us works, so it must not be what you are actually doing, but only what you mistakenly think you are doing.